# How to use select parameter in server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, morris.js

I want to use the select parameter in a node function parameter but i don't know how to do it.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function action(selectObject) {
  var periode=selectObject.value;
   }
    </script>

  <select id="list" onchange="action(this);">
  <option>Selectionnez la periode </option>
  <option value ="5">5</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
```

After that i need to use this period as a parameter in my calcul function

```
  var date=new Date("2017-07-26T00:00:00Z");    
  var period;
  app.get('/calcule', function(req, res){
  calcul.calcule(date,period,function(calcule){
 var datas= calcule;

  res.render('index1.ejs',{datas:datas});

  });

  });
```

I dont why it only work with the defaut value (5).When i choose an other option it did not work.
it's possible or no?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using `express framework` on serverside, you can put `periode` value as a `query string variable` to server.
In clientside

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function action(selectObject) {
     var periode=selectObject.value;
     window.location = '/calcule?period=' + periode;
     console.log(periode); // F12 chrome to view this value
  }
 </script>
```

In serverside

```
app.get('/calcule', function(req, res){
  // get data from querystring
  console.log(req.query); // object query
  period = req.query.period ? req.query.period : 5; // default req.query.period is 5
  console.log(period);
  // validate period
  // recheck calcule function because you set `date and period` varables is global
  calcul.calcule(date,period,function(calcule){
  var datas= calcule;

  res.render('index1.ejs',{datas:datas});

});
```

Comment: Just one more question please. Dont you know why with nodejs when i select a period from options it works only for the first time. After that i need to rerun the server to choose an other period??

Comment: @SirineAbed You can debug to sure bug on clientside or serverside. I Updated my anwser to show more log maybe help you debug it. Check value in URL in browser make sure it like `http://localhost/calcule?period=30`.

Comment: But the problem is that when i select an option(5,3,30) the chart that i want to display with the function "calcule" didnt work. It's only work with the defaut value  (5)                                                                                        
      period = req.query.period ? req.query.period : 5; // default 
     req.query.period is 5. Do you have any idea please?

Comment: @SirineAbed Show me `calcul.calcule` function and server log.

Comment: I updated my post. Can you please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: It works Now .The problem was in my calcule function. I write var data="[" out the function so i had an error on my datas . Thanks for your help